# Version of a built `conda-forge` package is different between `pip list` and the `conda list` (it should be the same)

Tags: conda-forge

I recently added the package `typepigeon` to `conda-forge`. On `conda-forge` it is currently at version `1.0.9`; however, when installing `typepigeon` via `conda install`, the output of `pip list` shows its version to be `0.0.0.post2.dev0+a27ab2a` instead of `1.0.9`.

`conda list`:

```
typepigeon                1.0.9              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
```

`pip list`:

```
typepigeon         0.0.0.post2.dev0+a27ab2a
```

I think the issue arises from the way I am assigning the version (I am using `dunamai` to extract the Git tag as the version number). This version extraction is done [within `setup.py` of `typepigeon`](https://github.com/zacharyburnett/TypePigeon/blob/deb0927e1089152759a585428857437a43de914b/setup.py#L6-L10).

```py
try:
    __version__ = Version.from_any_vcs().serialize()
except RuntimeError as error:
    warnings.warn(f'{error.__class__.__name__} - {error}')
    __version__ = '0.0.0'
```

When `conda-forge` builds the feedstock, I think it might be looking at the Git tag of the feedstock repository instead of the version from PyPI (as it is locally executing `setup.py`).

How can I modify the Conda Forge recipe to force the PyPI version?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out **a** solution; it might not be the best possible way to do this, but it works for my workflow.

I [injected the version into the `setup.py`](https://github.com/zacharyburnett/TypePigeon/commit/1a668d64b6c4229af253bc03708dcc7380d8d80b) by looking for an environment variable (that I called `__version__`):

```py
if '__version__' in os.environ:
    __version__ = os.environ['__version__']
else:
    from dunamai import Version

    try:
        __version__ = Version.from_any_vcs().serialize()
    except RuntimeError as error:
        warnings.warn(f'{error.__class__.__name__} - {error}')
        __version__ = '0.0.0'
```

Then, in the `conda-forge` recipe, I [added an environment variable (`__version__`) to the build step](https://github.com/conda-forge/typepigeon-feedstock/commit/9789ff0c34de347fc7a8bbece3444193459c409b):

```yaml
build:
  noarch: python
  script: export __version__={{ version }} && {{ PYTHON }} -m pip install . -vv
```